# Verify an Android device security PIN via API

Tags: android

Is it possible to programatically **verify** an android devices security PIN from an app? *(The numerical code used to unlock the device when it wakes up).*

I am not interested in retrieving the PIN itself, instead I am looking for a way use the API to submit a number sequence (e.g. `1234` or `0000`)  and get a boolean response stating whether the code is correct?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, sorry, there is no API for this, even within the device administration APIs.

Comment: The answer has been a while already, is the feature added to recent update(for example, Android M)?

Comment: @DinoTw: No, what the OP wants is still not possible. There are APIs in Android 6.0 that allow you to prompt the user to re-authenticate their device, by whatever means the user has set up (PIN, password, pattern, fingerprint, etc.). But you cannot feed in the data to test.